# Position a UIView at point of tap to launch popover

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uipopovercontroller

In what I think is a rather clever approach to getting around the problem of launching a popover from a `UITableViewRowAction`, I want to position a clear `UIView` over the target action and use it for the `sourceRect` to anchor the `UIPopoverPresentationController`. In this case the target action is the orange "Acct" button shown in the screenshot below.

I'm using a clear `UIView` (`self.clearTopView`) over the entire tableview and I init the launching view (`tappedViewOverlay`) with a frame derived from (so I thought) the location of the tap (`point`) in the view and a `CGSize` (`tappedRectSize`). Then I add it as a subview to `self.clearTopView`. I'm currently coloring it black so I can find it.

As shown in the following screenshot, part of the scheme is working according to plan. `tappedViewOverlay` view is added, and colored appropriately. The `popoverPresentationController` (`thisPPC`) is launched from this view, as intended.

[image]

Problem is that the view is always positioned in the upper left corner of the screen, instead of the desired location, which is where the tap occurred. Here's the relevant code:

```
    else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"AccountPopSegue"])
    {

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer;

        CGPoint point = [tapGestureRecognizer locationInView:self.clearTopView];

        NSString *pointString = NSStringFromCGPoint(point);

        NSLog(@"point is located at %@",pointString);


        CGSize tappedRectSize= CGSizeMake(60,60);
        CGRect tappedRect = {point,tappedRectSize};

        NSString * tappedRectString = NSStringFromCGRect(tappedRect);

        NSLog(@"tappedRect = %@",tappedRectString);


        tappedViewOverlay = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:tappedRect];
        tappedViewOverlay.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        [self.clearTopView addSubview:tappedViewOverlay];

        [self.clearTopView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];


        NSString *tappedOverlayFrame = NSStringFromCGRect(tappedViewOverlay.frame);
        NSLog(@"tappedViewOverlay.frame = %@",tappedOverlayFrame);


        UIViewController *controller = segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.popoverPresentationController.delegate = self;
        controller.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 186);
        UIPopoverPresentationController *thisPPC = controller.popoverPresentationController;


        thisNavController = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        AccountChangeVC *acCVC = (AccountChangeVC *)thisNavController.topViewController;
        acCVC.delegate = self;

        thisPPC.sourceView = self.clearTopView;
        thisPPC.sourceRect = tappedViewOverlay.bounds;
```

**Can someone please show me where I'm going wrong?**

**Edit**

CoderWang pointed out an oversight in my code, so I've corrected it:

```
    else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"AccountPopSegue"])
    {

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]init];

        [self.clearTopView addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];



        CGPoint point = [tapGestureRecognizer locationInView:self.clearTopView];

        NSString *pointString = NSStringFromCGPoint(point);

        NSLog(@"point is located at %@",pointString);


        CGSize tappedRectSize= CGSizeMake(60,60);

        CGRect tappedRect = {point,tappedRectSize};

        NSString * tappedRectString = NSStringFromCGRect(tappedRect);

        NSLog(@"tappedRect = %@",tappedRectString);


        tappedViewOverlay = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:tappedRect];

        tappedViewOverlay.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        [self.clearTopView addSubview:tappedViewOverlay];

        [self.clearTopView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];


        NSString *tappedOverlayFrame = NSStringFromCGRect(tappedViewOverlay.frame);
        NSLog(@"tappedViewOverlay.frame = %@",tappedOverlayFrame);


        UIViewController *controller = segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.popoverPresentationController.delegate = self;
        controller.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 186);
        UIPopoverPresentationController *thisPPC = controller.popoverPresentationController;


        thisNavController = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        AccountChangeVC *acCVC = (AccountChangeVC *)thisNavController.topViewController;
        acCVC.delegate = self;

        thisPPC.sourceView = self.clearTopView;
        thisPPC.sourceRect = tappedViewOverlay.bounds;
```

This change (initialization of the `tapGestureRecognizer` and addition to `self.clearTopView`) produces a slight change in the position of the black `tappedViewOverlay` view. You can see it hiding behind the "Back" nav button in the following screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that the 'tappedRect' is incorrect, don`t know the reason exactly.
But you can try the following method to get rect for "Acct" button converted to self.clearTopView :

```
CGRect tappedRect = [Acct.superview convertRect:acct.frame toView:self.clearTopView];
```

or converted to window (as self.clearTopView is over the entire tableview):

```
CGRect tappedRect = [Acct.superview convertRect:acct.frame toView:nil];
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, UITableViewRowAction buttons don't have a frame property, at least not one that's accessible...

Comment: Then you can use the related method: - (CGPoint)convertPoint:(CGPoint)point toView:(nullable UIView *)view; with CGPoint point = [tapGestureRecognizer locationInView:self.clearTopView];

Comment: It will be better if you also provide the log infos.

Comment: Here you go:

`point is located at {0, 0}
tappedRect = {{0, 0}, {60, 60}}
tappedViewOverlay.frame = {{0, 0}, {60, 60}}`

Comment: WOW，i found an issue:should not 'tapGestureRecognizer' be initialized first and then added to self.clearTopView?

Comment: You're quite correct, and I had the initialization code in earlier, but had commented it out for some reason, then deleted it. See edited question...

Comment: Not having enough reputation to 'move this discussion to chat' ：）

Try this:
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGestureRecogized:)];
    [self.clearTopView addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];

then get the point:
- (void)tapGestureRecogized:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGes {
    CGPoint point = [tapGes locationInView:self.clearTopView];
    
}

Comment: I implemented the code you supplied--thanks!--but it appears not to have made any difference. The origin of the view remains {0,0}